# node server is not starting

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js, pnpm

I'm building a web app with Next.js and everything was working fine. But now when I try to start the dev server after a 1-month break, it isn't starting and this error is thrown

[image]

I have tried deleting the `node_modules` folder and reinstalling all the packages, but still, the same error occurs.
I'm using `pnpm` btw...

Can someone please point out what might be missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is the node and pnpm version same as 1 month ago

Comment: @Sanket yes, they are the same version. I've also tried changing the node version, but still have the same error.